# Images are not visible in preview in email studio

Tags: salesforce, devexpress, html-email, salesforce-marketing-cloud

When I am trying to preview a HTML email in the email studio preview , it shows empty images but email looks fine in the INBOX.
Image size is width:600px and height:338px

[image]

Please help to resolve this issue in SFMC email studio
Also attaching html code of block

```html
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="oneColumn global" role="presentation" style="background-color: %%=v(@contentBgColor)=%%;" width="100%">
 
  <tr>
   <td align="center" style="padding: 0 0 20px;">
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" width="100%">
     
      <tr>
       <td align="center" style="background-color: %%=v(@imageFullBgColor)=%%;">
        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="margin: 0 auto;">
         
          <tr>
           <td align="center" style="width: 600px;">
            <a alias="" conversion="false" data-linkto="other" href="%%=RedirectTo(@Image_Component_One_Url)=%%" target="_blank" title=""><img alt="" data-assetid="500960" height="300" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/01/14/23/12/nature-3082832__480.jpg" style="width: 600px; max-width: 600px; max-height: 338px; display: block; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px none transparent; text-align: center; height: 300px;" width="600"></a> <a alias="" href="#tbd" target="_blank"> </a></td></tr></table></td></tr></table></td></tr></table>
```

Thanks in advance

I want to show images in the preview of the HTML email in the email studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Chrome then the issue is likely due to Chrome blocking mixed content.

For example if you dont have SSL included in your SAP, and you try to serve content over ssl then that content will be blocked. In your case you are serving up: **https**://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/01/14/23/12/nature-3082832__480.jpg

It can be determined whether or not the Private image domain (image endpoint) has SSL by navigating to Setup > Company Settings > Account Settings.

If an account HAS SSL the Portfolio Base URL will start with HTTPS.
If an account DOES NOT have SSL the Portfolio Base URL will start with HTTP.

More information can be found here: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000355099&type=1

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem in Chrome and Edge and can't find a reliable solution other than waiting as it seems to naturally fix itself.

If it's not working for you in Chrome switch to Edge or another browser, wait a few days and it should be working in Chrome.

Sorry for the not so helpful technical answer, but if it's helpful you are not alone.